# TYPO3 unable to fetch data with dataProcessing in template of custom content element

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I created a custom content element with a custom field.
I added the custom field like this in the overrides of tt_content.php

```
$elements = [
    'myCustomField' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'The label of my field',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_vendor_domain_model_myfavoritepictures,
            ],
        ],
    ],
  ];
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', $elements);
```

This field is included in the TCA of my custom content element, it stores the relations to chosen records which contain pictures.
The fluidtemplate of my custom content elements contains only a debug-viewhelper.

What I am trying to achieve is to fetch the pictures of the records, which are chosen in `myCustomField`. For that, I tried to use the "DatabaseQueryProcessor" as described in the official TYPO3 documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/DatabaseQueryProcessor.html

```
ce_mycustomcontentelement < lib.customContentElement
    ce_mycustomcontentelement {
        templateName = CeMyCustomContentElement
        dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
            if.isTrue.field = myCustomField
            table = tx_vendor_domain_model_myfavoritepictures
            as = myFavoritePictures
            // recursively process the files in the records with the FilesProcessor
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = picture
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, for the field "myFavoritePictures" which is defined in the dataProcessing Property, I am getting an empty array from the debug-viewhelper in my fluidtemplate of my custom content element. I am guessing, that i didn't cofigured the dataProcessing porperty correctly but unfortunately I don't know what might me wrong.

Comment: Maybe, you're struggling with the missing `pidInList`. If `pidInList` is not configured, the current page would be used for selecting records. If your `tx_vendor_domain_model_myfavoritepictures`records are not saved on the same page, nothing can be found. If your `tx_vendor_domain_model_myfavoritepictures`records are stored in a sysfolder, configure its PID as `pidInList`.

Comment: Thank you, after configuring `pidInList` the problem got solved